# Приложение для считывания данных с сайта

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, суть моей проблемы такова. Начальство поставило задачу - написать в виде теста программу, которая будет подключатся к тестовому сайту и брать оттуда данные.

Скажем сайт есть и там в файле выводиться одно слово. Требуется подключиться и вывести в приложении это слово и всё.

Проблема в том что я совсем не знаю Java и как программить под андроид. Я вообще веб-программер. А тут вот начальство решило так. Срок. Вы не поверите. Конец рабочего дня. Осталось 5 часов.

А я даже не знаю как загуглить свой вопрос.

Может есть какая то функция типа GetURL ('mysite.com') и оттуда извлекаются данные?

Прошу помощи опытных гуру!)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071568/parse-web-site-html-with-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071568/parse-web-site-html-with-java)

Answer (score 1):

самое простецкое
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/mybrowser.php